# how to send id of button clicked to command?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've got a button inside a datatemplate. When the button is clicked I'd like to send the id of the button to my command. The snippet below obviously dosn't work. What am i doing wrong?

```
<DataTemplate>
<Button CommandParameter="ProductId" x:Name="btnProduct" Width="180" Height="40" Content="{Binding DisplayText}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <n:ExecuteCommandAction Command="{Binding ShowSandwichPriceCommand}" 
                Parameter="{Binding ElementName=btnProduct, Path=SelectedValue}"
            />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>                           
</Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: i'm aware the above is broken.  what code makes this work?

Comment: I've modified my answer to fix the issue .. not sure if thats the outcome you expect though .. since i'm sure you want to test in the command to do stuff based on which control the command is invoked for

Comment: Are you trying to pass "ProductId" to the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to get my code working with this.  thanks.

```
<DataTemplate>
     <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.ShowSandwichPriceCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" 
          CommandParameter="{Binding Path=ProductId}" 
          Content="{Binding DisplayText}">                                        
     </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

The button element doesn't have the SelectedValue property.

You might want to use the Name propery instead or some other available property.

```
<DataTemplate>
<Button CommandParameter="ProductId" x:Name="btnProduct" Width="180" Height="40" Content="{Binding DisplayText}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <n:ExecuteCommandAction Command="{Binding ShowSandwichPriceCommand}" 
                Parameter="{Binding ElementName=btnProduct, Path=Name}"
            />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>                           
</Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I use Tag, but am unsure if that's the "best" way to do it.

Comment: @Dave If he uses "Tag" he has to set it to some value for each control that might want to use that command. It would work though.